# Array adapter don't show items after using set Text function

Tags: java, android, android-arrayadapter

I have a Button and `setOnClickListener`, where i create simple Linked List and Array Adapter

```
LinkedList<Double> rangeList = new LinkedList<>();
     for (double j = -20; j <= 30; j += 1) {
          rangeList.add(j / 10); }

ArrayAdapter<Double> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(requireContext(), R.layout.dropdown_item, rangeList); //Collections.singletonList(range)
            binding.idInjectionTimeData.setAdapter(arrayAdapter); //idInjectionTimeData is AutoCompleteTextView in xml
```

Now everything works.
But, if I just want to set initial value to my binding field (doesn't matter, what value), my application don't want to show  values, that i set in my Array Adapter.

```
binding.idInjectionTimeData.setText("1.3");
```

In the debugger, I noticed that before using `setText` my array Adapter object has a [mObject field with all values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dG5Xq.png) , and after using `setText`, [mObject has only one value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wlvvO.png) , which I used in `setText`, and the entire list of the Adapter's array has moved to `mOriginalValues`.

**In short:**
I want my application to [show my adapter like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9Qpf.png).

But after `setText`, the field is initialized, but stop showing my adapter list.

What is the problem? What i can read to know more about that? Or maybe there is a better, different way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SetText filters out the values of the adapter, you'll have to use the override of setText that takes in 2 parameters, text and filter